# Is it possible to return file from HttpResponseMessage type of [Httppost] in Asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

I am working on a project which convert file from html to pdf to get the pdf client first select html using file dialogue then post to controller than this controller receive file and convert into pdf successfully but problem is that he cannot download the file until the method is POST ,

**Controller**

```
   [HttpPost]
  public HttpResponseMessage Dashboard(HttpPostedFileBase file,string typeofmodel)
    {


    var htmlToPdf = new HtmlToPdfConverter();

        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        var pdfContentType = "application/pdf";
        // processing the stream.
        BinaryReader b = new BinaryReader(File.InputStream);
        byte[] binData = b.ReadBytes(File.ContentLength);

        string html = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(binData);
        stream.Write(htmlToPdf.GeneratePdf(html, null), 0, htmlToPdf.GeneratePdf(html, null).Length);

        var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Content = new ByteArrayContent(stream.ToArray())
        };
        result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition =
            new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
            {
                FileName = "Htmltopdf.pdf"
            };
        result.Content.Headers.ContentType =
            new MediaTypeHeaderValue(pdfContentType);

        return result;
    }
```

Here **HtmlToPdfConverter** is a class of NReco library which can be found [Here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NReco.PdfGenerator/)

**Output**

> StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.ByteArrayContent, Headers: { Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Htmltopdf.pdf Content-Type: application/pdf }

Please help how can I return download? using **HTTPPOST** only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HttpResponseMessage is stringyfied because it's not an ActionResult.
Controller's actions must return an ActionResult :

```
public ActionResult Dashboard(HttpPostedFileBase file,string typeofmodel)
{


   var htmlToPdf = new HtmlToPdfConverter();

    var stream = new MemoryStream();
    var pdfContentType = "application/pdf";
    // processing the stream.
    BinaryReader b = new BinaryReader(File.InputStream);
    byte[] binData = b.ReadBytes(File.ContentLength);

    string html = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(binData);
    stream.Write(htmlToPdf.GeneratePdf(html, null), 0, htmlToPdf.GeneratePdf(html, null).Length);

    return File(stream, pdfContentType, "Htmltopdf.pdf"); 

}
```